# Java class as condition in generic method

Tags: java

I have a Service which is responsible to gather some information through Providers. Depending on the information required, a certain Provider has to be used. For now the Provider is chosen upon a given Class. This example is simplified, but it should give a reasonable understanding of my setup

```
abstract class AbstractProvider {

    private String provider = "MyProvider";

    public String doSomethingAwsome() {
        return provider;
    }
    
}

class ProviderA extends AbstractProvider {

    @Override
    public String doSomethingAwsome() {
        return super.doSomethingAwsome() + "_A";
    }
}

class ProviderB extends AbstractProvider {

    @Override
    public String doSomethingAwsome() {
        return super.doSomethingAwsome() + "_B";
    }
}

class MyService {
    private ProviderA providerA;
    private ProviderB providerB;

    MyService() {
        providerA = new ProviderA();
        providerB = new ProviderB();
    }

    public <T extends AbstractProvider> String doSomethingWithProvider(Class<T> providerClass) {
        if (providerClass.equals(ProviderA.class)) {
            return providerA.doSomethingAwsome();
        } else if (providerClass.equals(ProviderB.class)) {
            return providerB.doSomethingAwsome();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Provider found for Class: " + providerClass);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyService myService = new MyService();

        String fromProviderA = myService.doSomethingWithProvider(ProviderA.class);
        String fromProviderB = myService.doSomethingWithProvider(ProviderB.class);

        System.out.printf("Provider A: %s, Provider B: %s", fromProviderA, fromProviderB);
    }
}
```

Now I'm not happy with the solution in `MyService.doSomethingWithProvider()`. How would you implement this?

Is there a generic way of choosing the Provider? I dont like to use if-else clauses here.

### Edit

Based on some suggestions, using a map seems better

```
class MyService {
    private Map<Class<? extends AbstractProvider>, AbstractProvider> providers = new HashMap<>();

    MyService() {
        providers.put(ProviderA.class, new ProviderA());
        providers.put(ProviderB.class, new ProviderB());
    }

    public <T extends AbstractProvider> String doSomethingWithProvider(Class<T> providerClass) {
        if (providers.containsKey(providerClass)) {
            return providers.get(providerClass).doSomethingAwsome();
        }
        new IllegalArgumentException("No Provider found for Class: " + providerClass)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using a [chain of responsibility (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: You could use a map.

Comment: Why not!? The visibility is "strange", but... 1 (small) improvement (for more providers, big improvement): don't hold reverence to `ProviderXYZ...`, but better (when you access them by class) `Map<Class<T>, Object<T>>` (t extends...)

Comment: Then "just": `return map.get(clazz).doSomething..,,` (without ifs)

Answer (score 0):

Turing85 suggested to have a look at the Chain of Responsibility design pattern. Honestly I had to dig a little deeper for this one. The idea is quite easy to understand but getting my head around the implementation took me a little further.

So thanks for your input, I'm happy with this

```
abstract class AbstractProvider {
    private String provider = "MyProvider";
    public AbstractProvider nextProcessor;

    public AbstractProvider(AbstractProvider nextProcessor) {
        this.nextProcessor = nextProcessor;
    }

    public String doSomethingAwsome() {
        return provider;
    }

    public abstract <T extends AbstractProvider> String doSomethingAwsome(Class<T> provider) throws IllegalArgumentException;

}

class ProviderA extends AbstractProvider {

    public ProviderA (AbstractProvider nextProvider) {
        super(nextProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomethingAwsome() {
        return super.doSomethingAwsome() + "_A";
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends AbstractProvider> String doSomethingAwsome(Class<T> provider) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (provider.equals(this.getClass())) {
            return this.doSomethingAwsome();
        } else if (nextProcessor != null) {
            return nextProcessor.doSomethingAwsome(provider);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No provider found for class: " + provider);
    }
}

class ProviderB extends AbstractProvider {

    public ProviderB (AbstractProvider nextProvider) {
        super(nextProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomethingAwsome() {
        return super.doSomethingAwsome() + "_B";
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends AbstractProvider> String doSomethingAwsome(Class<T> provider) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (provider.equals(this.getClass())) {
            return this.doSomethingAwsome();
        } else if (nextProcessor != null) {
            return nextProcessor.doSomethingAwsome(provider);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No provider found for class: " + provider);
    }
}

class MyService {
    private AbstractProvider providerChain;

    MyService() {
        providerChain = new ProviderA(new ProviderB(null));
    }

    public <T extends AbstractProvider> String doSomethingWithProvider(Class<T> providerClass) {
        return providerChain.doSomethingAwsome(providerClass);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can do several more improvements here. Don't hesitate to give me your input